# Is my asphalt driveway beyond repair?

Tags: repair, driveway, asphalt, cracks

My asphalt driveway appears to have 2 layers of asphalt on it.
The top layer is full of cracks.... resulting in many small pieces of asphalt....
As if someone dropped it and it "shattered".....  The pieces are still intact for the most part.
There're some larger cracks as well... which could likely be repaired....
My question is... can my overall driveway be repaired?? Can I add another layer on top of this?
Or does this situation require a complete removal / replacement??  There are no low spots.

Comment: The two existing layers were not bond adequately. Also, place one layer over another layer is like adding new material over bad foundation. I suggest to remove the top layer, or both, if the lowest layer is in a bad shape too.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, what type of weather do you have?

Comment: A picture may help .there also "chip and seal" bituminous pavements.

Comment: Absolutely agree with blacksmith, sealing cracks then a overlay can extend a asphalt driveway’s life. In some cases sealing adds the tar that the original job skimped on to save $. Sealing cracks and chunks then chip sealing can rejuvenate your driveway and save more than 1/2 the cost of a full overlay and 2-3x a demo and new base.

Answer (score 1):

When my son bought his "new to him" house, the asphalt driveway was a mess. He did not have the funds necessary to replace the driveway so I came up with a plan to try to extend the life of his driveway. We mixed white play sand with a driveway sealer at about 1 part of the sand to 2 parts of the sealer. His driveway was quite long and we used about 75- 5 gallon drums of sealer plus sand. We put it on with squeeges and it filled all but the widest cracks where pieces were missing. In those areas we did a double and sometimes a triple coat of the sand/sealer mix. Shazam, like magic his driveway looked like new. This fix lasted 3-4 years until he could afford to replace the driveway.